# Image Upload internal server error Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, internal-server-error

I am getting an internal server error when I am attempting to upload images in the Ruby app I am working on. I know what the issue is itself, however I am not entirely sure how to fix it. As of now this is how the app works:

User visits page, is allowed to upload images and then the handling of the images will be done after upload. Therefore I am creating a new Gallery instance when the user visits the page (Galleries hold one or many Pictures). The issue is in my gallery controller where I am attempting to create the follwing:

```
    def index
    @gallery = Gallery.create
    @picture = @gallery.pictures.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @galleries }
    end
  end
```

Annddd the error that follows when running "localhost:3000/galleries/"

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 148ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gallery_pictures_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001023d8b98>:0x00000102383670>):
    3: <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.fileupload-ui.js' %>
    4: 
    5: 
    6: <%= form_for [@gallery, @picture], :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload" } do |f| %>
    7: 
    8:     <div>
    9:         <div class=" fileupload-buttonbar">
  app/views/galleries/index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_galleries_index_html_erb__2795478836341012416_2164674980'
  app/controllers/galleries_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

The project itself is on GitHub here: https://github.com/dflynn15/UploaderTest

The issue is either with my understanding of Gallery.create and how a new instance is created (I know the risk of orphan instances running around but I am going to implement a expiration date after I get this uploading issue fixed), or my understanding of how Pictures and Gallery are connected disallowing @gallery.pictures to be an invalid path.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in routes.rb

```
resources :galleries, :shallow => true do
    resources :pictures
end
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I forgot to fix my routes. Thanks for catching that bit of idiocy.